# Can you select every value in a table if one value exists?

Tags: mysql

How can I get all the values in a table if the value that I'm checking against exists in a schema like this ? [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae8274/1)

```
CREATE TABLE children (
  id int,
  name varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE classrooms (
  id int,
  name varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE childrenToClassrooms (
  childId int,
  classRoomId int 
);

INSERT INTO children (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Mike');
INSERT INTO children (id, name) VALUES (2, 'Jake');
INSERT INTO children (id, name) VALUES (3, 'Arnold');
INSERT INTO children (id, name) VALUES (4, 'Alan');

INSERT INTO classrooms (id, name) VALUES (1, 'class1');

INSERT INTO childrenToClassrooms (childId, classRoomId) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO childrenToClassrooms (childId, classRoomId) VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO childrenToClassrooms (childId, classRoomId) VALUES (3, 1);
```

So I want to return all the children from a class only if the child that makes the request is part of that class, can this be done in one query ?

```
SELECT children.name FROM children
INNER JOIN childrenToClassrooms ON childrenToClassrooms.childId = children.id AND classrooms.id = 1
-- IF childrenToClassrooms.childId = 1 exists ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use the childrenToClasstooms twice:

1. get "child_id"
2. find all the classes related to this child (see FROM + WHERE)
3. find all the children related to these classes (see 1st JOIN)
4. get the children details (see 2nd JOIN)

Here's the query:

```
SELECT  children.*

FROM    childrenToClassrooms            AS  childClassrooms

JOIN    childrenToClassrooms            AS  classroomsChildren
    ON  classroomsChildren.classRoomId  =   childClassrooms.classRoomId

JOIN    children                        AS  children
    ON  children.id                     =   classroomsChildren.childId

WHERE   childClassrooms.childId         =   @child_id
```

if you have also the class_id you can add it to the WHERE clause